# How to guess order of items in rampart having WS-Security response?

Tags: java, apache-axis, webservice-client, ws-security, rampart

My axis2+rampart client worked with some WS-Secured server. It stopped working after server was upgraded (JBoss upgrade, some changes in WSDL, but not in test function). Server owners claim that their WS-Security configuration was not changed, but now my client reports:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Must Understand check failed for header http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd : Security
```

Earlier I got this exception when order of "items" in `axis2.xml` was not good.
All I had to do was to combine those items. They look like:

```
<parameter name="InflowSecurity">
  <action>
    <items>Signature Encrypt Timestamp</items>
...
```

Now this problem reappeared. I see that in reply there is no 'Timestamp'. I removed that from items but nothing changed.

Reply looks like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="..."
    xmlns:xenc="...">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security
            xmlns:wsse="..."
            soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="..."
                Id="EncKeyId-B8B3555394366F3F0112919826983351032">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="..." />
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="...">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference
                        xmlns:wsse="...">
                        <wsse:KeyIdentifier
                            ...
                        </wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>
                        ...
                    </xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:ReferenceList>
                    <xenc:DataReference URI="#EncDataId-624" />
                </xenc:ReferenceList>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="..."
                Id="Signature-622">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod
                        Algorithm="..." />
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="..." />
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-623">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="..." />
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="..." />
                        <ds:DigestValue>
                            ...
                        </ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>
                    ...
                </ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-B8B3555394366F3F0112919826983181029">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference
                        xmlns:wsse="..."
                        xmlns:wsu="..."
                        wsu:Id="STRId-B8B3555394366F3F0112919826983181030">
                        <wsse:KeyIdentifier
                            EncodingType="..."
                            ValueType="...">
                            ...
                        </wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body xmlns:ns1="..."
        xmlns:wsu="..."
        wsu:Id="id-623">
        <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="..."
            Id="EncDataId-624" Type="...">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="..." />
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="...">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference
                    xmlns:wsse="...">
                    <wsse:Reference
                        xmlns:wsse="..."
                        URI="#EncKeyId-B8B3555394366F3F0112919826983351032" />
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:CipherValue>
                    ...
                </xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My questions:

1. How can I know what part of security really failed? Is it wrong order, lack of some element, some element extra or similar error?
2. How can I guess what items should I add to rampart InflowSecurity configuration if all I had is signed and encrypted reply? Is there way to know what order of items should I use?

Answer (score 1):

That's rather old question, but as I just finished my journey through that land of pain, I'll share the answers.

a) The order of items is enforced by underlying wss4j library, not by rampart. The problematic method is checkReceiverResults() from org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler. You probably ran into problems by using rampart WSDoAllReceiver which is extending WSHandler.

b) Good news is that checkReceiverResults() method is protected. So you can extend WSDoAllReceiver and override the method to make it more permissive. I suggest looking at checkReceiverResultsAnyOrder() implementation added to WSHandler in wss4j-1.5.8.

So to answer your questions:

You can debug checkReceiverResults() method to find out and "fix" order of items in your axis2.xml file. But that's not a good way to go, as the order of headers may always change (there is no requirement for order of elements in SOAP header). So my suggestion is calling checkReceiverResultsAnyOrder() rather than checkReceiverResults().